# How to Trim the first two characters of a column in csv using groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

```
<taskdef  name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>                                                                      
     <groovy>            
    newFile("C://RxBen//exports//Control_Exception__c_Exportupdated.csv").withWriter {                                          
    new File("C://RxBen//exports//Control_Exception__c_Export.csv").splitEachLine(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*\$)") { ID, Don_t_Work__c,Forwarding_fax_number__c, No_Go__c  ->
     it.println "${ID},${Forwarding_fax_number__c}AAA,${s}"                                                           
     }                                             
    }                             
    </groovy>
```

Comment: Please add your example expected output.

Comment: Please check with my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring on the String in the column with the argument of 2, this will take all the characters from third character to the end of the string in the target String.

Example:

```
def s = "AATestString"
def newString = s.substring(2)
assert newString == "TestString"
```

Comment: This will work for constant string. I have a csv file with column having 20 values and i want to trim the first two characters of those 20 values

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
Try with this code: which  Ozsaffer approached ...

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv 

df = new FileReader('filename.csv') 

def data = parseCsv(df, readFirstLine: false) 

for (def row : data){

println row.values[0].substring(2)  //row.values[0] means first column 
}
```

Comment: Do we need to install seperate csvparser.jar to run this?

Comment: @user3595098 This code runs with internet connectivity.So  Make sure of it. or download jar from maven.

Comment: What all Jar files i need to download and where i have to paste it? inside lib folder? and how can i add this groovy script inside my ANT build.xml?